# MFC - Format rtf document to two columns

Tags: mfc

I am merging many rtf files into a single file for printing. In order to save paper, I would like to have the printout of the merged rtf document in two columns per page.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a way of doing this.

1. Load the rtf document into a CRichEditCtrl.
2. Use the CRichEditCtrl's FormatRange method to format and render the text to different part of the paper; left column and right column in this case.